# Find probabilistic rank in log n time

Tags: algorithm, probability

You are given a sequence a1,a2.....an of real numbers. We would like to find a number whose rank is
greater than n/2. Design an O(log n) algorithm, which will find a number whose rank is greater than n/2
with probability greater than 1-1/n.
Note : 1. The numbers are not sorted.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with rank? Is the sequence ordered? Are you sure that probability is correct, shouldn't it be 1/(n-1) instead?

Comment: Also, do you have random access to the sequence?

Comment: @NamelessOne The sequence is not ordered..I have edited the question..sorry for the mistake.. Rank of a element X is equal to  the no of elements that are less than element X +1.

Comment: @JimMischel Yes we have random access.

Comment: Yeah well, if it was ordered then you could do it in O(1).

Comment: All you have to do is figure out how many elements you have to check before the probability is high enough. One element gives n/2n, more elements give 1 - (n/2n) * (n-1/2n) * (n-2/2n) * etc. I don't see how this would arrive at log n though.

Comment: @popovitsj but the sequence is not ordered..Any hint how can we do that...

Comment: What I mean is: if you take the first element your probability is .5, and it keeps increasing with every element you check. So you have to figure out how many elements you have to check. Actually: what you have to do is prove that you have to check log n elements to arrive at 1-1/n probability.

Comment: @user2677679 You should improve your question using [edit].

Comment: Does the number picked actually have to be an element in the sequence?

Answer (score 3):

Assume that n is even. The obvious thing to do is to sample lg n elements uniformly at random with replacement and return the maximum. The probability that the maximum is not in the upper half is the probability that all lg n samples are from the lower half. Each sample is in the lower half with probability 1/2, so the probability of failure is (1/2)^(lg n) = 1/n.

Comment: So you said in one simple paragraph what took me a freaking book to hint at. Nice job.

Answer (score -2):

This question has the premisse that this can be done in O(log n). Since the sequence is unordered, all you can do is check the first log n elements and return the highest.

I don't know if this really returns a higher than 2/nth ranked element more than 1-1/n of the times, but you didn't ask for the mathematical proof, just for the algorithm.

Python pseudocode:

```
max = None
for i in 0 to log(len(a)):
    if (max == None or a[i] > max:
         max = a[i]
return max
```

Comment: that's a pretty bold assumption. just to state the obvious, O(log n) != log n

Comment: What's a bold assumption?

Comment: @popovitsj There exists an algorithm which runs in O(logn) time and can find a number whose rank is greater than n/2 with probability greater than 1-1/n. This algorithm can't be any random algorithm of just O(logn) complexity.

Comment: @user2677679 With the limited information you provided, this is the best you can do. Good chance that you're holding out on some crucial bits of information though.

Comment: @user2677679: Actually, it could be that obvious, the difficulty is in proving/disproving that such a simple approach would have the desired probability. Though, if it doesn't, then it's probably likely that your answer is missing some key information, as it looks straightforward and doesn't seem like there's much choice other than randomly picking O(log N) elements. Although, better if it was adjusted to actually pick random elements rather than assuming the elements are random enough to just pick the first ones. There are methods to pick O(k) random elements without replacement in O(k) time.